# My Use of Zero Width Space is breaking dates

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Currently I am trying to fix word break in a html table due to overly long words due to the use of "/".

Example: VeryLongWord/AnotherLongWord

and I am trying to breaking this conjoined word into:

VeryLongWord/

AnotherLongWord

by allowing it to break naturally on the slash.

I am trying to do this break by the use of Zero Width space character (&#8239)
and it is working well...but only for characters.

When applied to the entire column of the table, dates in the column turn into boxes.

like this: 10//

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("printIssue");
         for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
            x[i].innerHTML = x[i].innerHTML.replace(/(\/)/g, "/&#8239");
```

The data in the cells themselves are not accessible/changeable by me, so I must fix it on the front end using JS/CSS/HTML.

Is there any tricks I can use with regex to ignore dates when selecting "/"?

Comment: HTML entities must end with a semi-colon.

Comment: Once you get this working, here's another thing to think about: if one of your users does a copy/paste from your table, those characters will go along with the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `<wbr />` tag instead of `&#8239;` to get a word break *without* hyphen only where needed. Or use the `&shy;` entity to get a word break *with* hyphen only where needed.

```js
const text = 'LongWord/NextWord and a date 20210/02/16';
let result1 = text.replace(/\//g, '/<wbr />');
let result2 = text.replace(/\/(?!\d)/g, '/<wbr />');
$('#orig').html(text);
$('#result1').html(result1);
$('#result2').html(result2);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 90%;
}
div {
  width: 4.5em;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background-color: #f0fff0;
  border: 1px dotted #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<p>Original</p>
<div id="orig"></div>
<p>Result 1</p>
<div id="result1"></div>
<p>Result 2</p>
<div id="result2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Run this code snippet to see.

- Original shows the original text
- Result 1 shows an optional word break using `<wbr />`
- Result 2 is like Result 1, but excludes a word break for dates, e.g. if the char after the slash is a digit

Answer (score 3):

HTML entities must end with a semi-colon.  Since you do not include it, a digit *following* the insertion point will be regarded part of the unicode point value, and will therefore produce a different, potentially undefined character. This is indeed the case with dates in ../../.. format. For instance, this:

```
10/11/21
```

...will be replaced by your code into:

```
10/&#823911/&#823921
```

And these were not the Unicode points (#823911 and #823921) you intended.

So add the semicolon terminator:

```
.replace(/(\/)/g, "/&#8239;");
```